# Leaflet Routing Machine calculate routes in loop

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I have an array with coordinates ([[54.73, 55.74], [55.66, 54.73]...]). I want to get route from each point to another. E.g. if I have 3 points a1, a2, a3, I want to calculate routes a1a2, a1a3, a2a1, a2a3 etc. I need this to make distance matrix later. Here is my loop where `coords` is array of coordinates

```
function routingLoop() {
            for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++){
                for (var j = 0; j < coords.length; j++){
                    var routing;
                    routing = L.routing.control({
                        waypoints:[
                            L.latLng(coords[i][0], coords[i][1]),
                            L.latLng(coords[j][0], coords[j][1]),
                        ],
                    }).addTo(Map);
                }
            }
        }
```

But I get this error `Routing error: 
Object { status: -3, message: "TypeError: this._altContainer is undefined" }`. Any ideas what's wrong with that code?

Comment: Its possible that its a problem that is not in that code. For example, maybe you haven't set Leaflet up correctly? Maybe try doing a really simple example (without the loops) that demonstrates the problem in one of the javascript test sites and posting that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure everything is fine with leaflet because it works well when I try routing without loop

Comment: Does it work if you avoid trying to route from i to j where i and j are the same? For example, check if `i === j` and `continue` the loop.

Comment: @BradHards as it turned out LRM can't route like a1a1 (distance == 0, time == 0), but I need it so I just used mapbox direction api for that purpose

Answer (score 2):

It might look dumb but that's how I did it after all. Hope someday someone will find it useful. Basically I just calculated routes using mapbox directions api (it's free and you can send up to 300 requests per/min) and used it's summary (btw it appears to me that the most comfortable way is to use LRM ONLY to draw nice looking routes and if you need some data about it, better use OSRM or another routing api)

```
function getRoutSummary(i, j) {
                var url = 'https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/driving/' +
                        coords[i][1] + ',' + coords[i][0] + ';' +
                        coords[j][1] + ',' + coords[j][0] +
                        '?geometries=geojson&access_token=YOUR TOKEN HERE';

                var req = new XMLHttpRequest();    
                req.responseType = 'json';    
                req.open('GET', url, true);

                req.onload = function () {
                    var jsonResponse = req.response;
                    var distance = jsonResponse.routes[0].distance;
                    console.log('Distance between ' +
                        'coords[' + i  +'][1]' + ',' + 'coords[' + i + '][0]' + ' and ' +
                        'coords[' + j  +'][1]' + ',' + 'coords[' + j + '][0]' +
                        ' is ' + distance);                    
                };
                req.send();
        }
```

`console.log` only to make me comfortable. And then iterate through array of coordinates

```
function getAllRoutes(){
            console.log('Begin getAllRoutes');
            for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++){
                for (var j = 0; j < coords.length; j++){
                    getRoutSummary(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Questions shuld go to questions, not answers. Nobody will look for questions in answers.

Comment: Forgot to delete it, sorry